# HVAC heat pump struggling with (new to me) laser vacuum sounds

Tags: hvac, heat-pump

Ok.  I'm a decent DIYer, and have done a few repairs with my HVAC heat pump system.

Less than 2 years old professionally installed unit.

This sound is new to me.

https://youtu.be/rJI_W5lvd3Q?si=CAVJhLG6oQyM6khp

BH16NA030-B
Carrier

[image]

It's during cold 30 degree weather...unit calling for heat.

Sounds like a bad 70s movie  laser torpedo fight.

I uploaded to u tub3 because I couldn't find the words to describe it well.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Try raising the setpoint for auxiliary resistive heat to take over for the heatpump. Your heat pump is not handling the 30 F outside temp. This may mean a service call, but that noise sounds like damage might be being done to the unit. The unit may simply have a "standard" setting and an "eco" setting. If it is in eco change to standard.

Comment: Something ain't right. What's the model of this unit? We can look up the spec for minimum temperature. I'm assuming 30F is within the range if it's modern, but maybe not if it's bargain basement grade.

Comment: Thank you. Fortunately, it is warming up a bit, and I have 2 units. So I have turned off the torpedo unit for now.  I am traveling early this week for work :( so I will post the model number when I get back.  I was "packing for the trip" when I got this short sound video.....so it was a hectic day.  Usually I take a picture of the magic numbers.  :(

Comment: Ok.  Finally back home.  Carrier BH16NA030-B

Comment: Hi.  Unit is less than 2 years old (based on my install date).  NC, so 30F outside should be a easy for this thing.  I "paid more" for a better SEER unit too.